# TeamCity dotnet test: MSBUILD : error MSB1021: Cannot create an instance of the logger. The given assembly name was invalid

Tags: .net, .net-core, teamcity

Since the xUnit TeamCity plugin does not seem to work with .NET core I am trying to run my .NET 7 tests on TeamCity build server with the .NET runner via docker.

However, I get following error when the command is executed in the build logs:

```
Step 1/5: MyProject.Tests (.NET)
   Response File
   Running step within container mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
   dotnet test
     Starting: .NET SDK 7.0.400 /usr/bin/dotnet test /opt/buildagent/work/e6d03f2b6a0fbca2/MyProject.Tests/MyProject.Tests.csproj --framework net7.0 --configuration Release @/opt/buildagent/temp/agentTmp/1.rsp
     in directory: /opt/buildagent/work/e6d03f2b6a0fbca2
     MSBUILD : error MSB1021: Cannot create an instance of the logger. The given assembly name was invalid.
     Switch: TeamCity.MSBuild.Logger.TeamCityMSBuildLogger,/opt/buildagent/plugins/dotnet/tools/msbuild15/TeamCity.MSBuild.Logger.dll;TeamCity;verbosity=detailed;plain
     Process exited with code 1
     Process exited with code 1 (Step: MyProject.Tests (.NET))
   Step MyProject.Tests (.NET) failed
```

I am using following configuration:

[image]

I tried many variations to change the assembly path but nothing works. Locally everything works fine. Docker seems also to be working and I mapped the /opt/* volumes correctly for the teamcity-agent.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

(FYI: I changed the project name for the post)